# identify past malicious transitions on blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, transactions, ether, golang

Do you know any way to identify past malicious transitions on blockchain?
Like if you see a large number of transactions going to a single address, or if you see transactions that seem to be moving large amounts of money back and forth between a small number of addresses, these could be signs of potential issues.
or maybe patterns or anomalies that could indicate suspicious activity, such as a high volume of transactions, frequent movements of large amounts of money, or interactions with known malicious addresses or entities.

Any tips would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of thing we used workers(scripts) of Nodejs and dotnet. Like we watch TXs of sepecific amount and wallets created on our blockchain and we note all address who come to our exchange and swaps or add liquidty. So, You can use it in the Centralized way, By making scripts.